# Ruby 2.3: Cannot duplicate an array. Original array modified

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm performing operations on arrays and I'm running into some issues.  I duplicated `array_1` assigning it to `array_2`. When I did operations on array_2, the `uniq` method modifies the original array.

`array_3` is what I intended accomplish, but I don't understand why the operations to get there modified `array_1`

I need an explanation why this behavior occurs, and what I can do to prevent this from happening.

```
array_1 = [["Ed","2",],["Ann","2"],["Sue","2"],["Ed","3",],["Ann","3"],["Sue","3"]]

array_2 = array_1.dup
array_2 = array_2.uniq(&:first)

array_3=[]
array_2.each do |a2|
  a2.pop
  array_3.push(a2)
end

puts array_3
=> [["Ed"], ["Ann"], ["Sue"]]

puts array_1
=> [["Ed"], ["Ann"], ["Sue"], ["Ed", "3"], ["Ann", "3"], ["Sue", "3"]]
```

Comment: http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
array_2 = array_1.dup
```

From the docs:

> **dup**
>
> Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.

So `array_2` consists of pointers to the same subarrays that are in `array_1`. Now `pop` mutates its array. So when you `pop` a subarray in `array_2`, it affects the same subarray in `array_1`.

You'll get the result you seem to expect if you say

```
array_2 = array_1.map(&:dup)
```

Personally, though, I would change

```
a2.pop
array_3.push(a2)
```

to

```
array_3.push(a2[0])
```

I don't see what you gain by mutating the subarrays (though perhaps something is going on that you have not told us).

Comment: Please don't advise people to do `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(array_1))`, or at least mention that it's almost always the wrong solution. In this case `array_1.map(&:dup)` would suffice.

Comment: this is part of a larger program.  I need to keep the sub arrays intact. I'm using these examples to learn the inner workings of ruby when a problem stumps me

Comment: That is why I said that perhaps something is going on that you have not told us.